# Unable to read data from the uart port of Beaglebone

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, uart

I'm facing a problem of getting values from my uart1 port of the Beaglebone Black, it is not displaying anything. The python code is attached as below, is there any error in my python code?

```
   import serial
   import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
   from time import sleep
   UART.setup("UART1")
   ser=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyO1',baudrate=9600)
   ser.open()

   while(1):
     while ser.inWaiting()==0:
            pass
     NMEA1=ser.readline()
     print NMEA1
   GPS.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before being able to use the UART you have to activate it during boot time.

In order to achieve it edit **`/dev/uEnv.txt`** and make sure a line like this one is there:

```
cape_enable=bone_capemgr.enable_partno=BB-UART1
```

Make sure there is no leading `#` commenting the line.

Also, check the baudrate at the other side of the connection is configured to the same value.